# Can we create instance of typed class, by calling class#newInstance()

Tags: java, generics

look at this:

```
package test;

public abstract class BaseClass {
    public abstract void doSomething();
}
```

```
package test;

public class A extends BaseClass {

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("A");
    }

}
```

```
package test;

public class GenericFoo<T extends BaseClass>{

    public GenericFoo(){

    }

    private T instance;

    public void  setType(String type){
        // client code  call this to set concrete type of T
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        instance.doSomething();
    }

    public static void main(String s) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{
        GenericFoo<?> obj = GenericFoo.class.newInstance();
        obj.setType("A");
        // I want  it to print "A" on console
        obj.doSomething();

    }
}
```

how to implement this, **my class is  only allowed to create instance with calling** `class#newInstance()` , but it's typed.

Comment: Reflection and generics don't go together _that_ well due to type erasure.  I'm not sure what you're asking for is strictly possible.

Comment: sorry, I asked a stupid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot set the type of an object at run time; you can only create instances of specific types. Once an instance of `GenericFoo` has been created, there's no way to set it's type parameter. (Due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), that doesn't even make sense at run time anyway.)

The best you can do is something like this:

```
private static class GenericFoo<T extends BaseClass>
{
    T createInstance(Class<T> clazz)
    {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: @AmirAfghani - Pretty much. The "requirement" to use `newInstance` is odd; perhaps this is homework and OP as gotten a little off track somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mix Generics and Reflections. Type safe is only available at compile time. But if you want to create simple object using your current configuration you can do it as

```
 GenericFoo<?> obj = new GenericFoo<BaseClass>();
 GenericFoo<BaseClass> obj = new GenericFoo<BaseClass>();
```

Comment: thanks dude! However, for some reason, client code can only call GenericFoo.class.createInstance() to  create an instance

Comment: GenericFoo<?> obj = GenericFoo.class.newInstance(); its creating the instance but  what exactly you required then?